# Insert Access 2003 table data into SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I need to insert data from access 2003 table (only some columns) into sql server 2008 table.
Please reply if anyone knows how to connect to the sql server from access and do the above functionlity.
A great thanks in advance.

Regards,
Karthik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not trying to import, rather trying to actually maintain though access, then [linked tables](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/link-tables-in-an-access-project-by-using-the-link-table-wizard-adp-HP003089371.aspx) is the best approach in my opinion.

A linked table allows you to connect to many different types of sources, read, update, delete depending on permissions.